# Session changes on page refresh in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, middleware

I am running on Laravel 5.2. Every time I run page refresh the session id changes. I haven't added 'Web middleware' as it's added by default to routes.php. Found like this issues floating on forums but none really seems to be the solution. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you setup your application id? php artisan generate:key

Comment: @Hassan, yes it is set.

Comment: Yes, I regenerate the app key using php artisan key:generate. But it doesn't help. Each time on page refresh the session()->getId() changes.

Answer (score 0):

We got threw this error too, and this is what seems to fix the problem :

• Check that your storage/ folder have the correct right

• Try to disable all the Javascript in your pages (either by disabling it via navigator or inside the code) and make sure that 'http_only' => true,

• Try to use with and without https

• Make sure the SESSION_DRIVER variable is NOT null

• Try to switch between 'encrypt' => false, and 'encrypt' => true,

• Try to change the cookie name 'cookie' => 'laravelsession',

• Try either to set your SESSION_DOMAIN to your actual domain OR null

• Try to switch between 'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false), and 'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),

After every step, this bug seems to be fixed, but somehow, the cookie still is not set in the navigator sometime until we use https on development too.

I am sorry not to be able to provide a 100% fix, but having the EXACT same issue, I wanted to share my experience with you.

Comment: Doesn't help. Giving more information session_id() doesn't change value on page refresh with normal php. But session()->getId() in Laravel 5.2 changes each time on page refresh.

Comment: @MirMumtaz Hi, you solved your issue, Because i have face same issue. Please provide solution if you solved this issue.